# Can't further optimize simple Python function

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I can't optimize it enough for it to run within the time frame given.

The full instructions can be found here (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem), but they're a bit longish.
I basically have two arrays: one is a leaderboard with high scores and the other is a list with the player's scores. I have to output another array with the player's rankings for every score (e.g. 1, 4, 8 for 1st, 4th, 8th).

This is my functioning, but slow function:

```
def climbingLeaderboard(ranked, player):
    rankings = []
    
    # Making it a set to remove duplicates
    ranked = list(set(ranked))

    # Sorting only once outside of loop
    ranked.sort()
    
    for score in player:
        # Duplicates must be avoided at all times
        if score not in ranked:
            # Used to avoid sorting at every iteration
            bisect.insort(ranked, score)

        # List was sorted ascending, but I need it descending
        # There were a -1 and +1 which offset each other in order to convert from index to ranking
        result = len(ranked) - ranked.index(score)
        rankings.append(result)

        # I don't fully get why, but this part can be omitted
        # rankings.remove(score)
        
    return rankings
```

I used the bisect.insort() to avoid sorting the list for every iteration of the loop.
I guess the heaviest part is converting to set and then again to list, but I honestly don't know how I could further optmize this.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove sorting and inserts**

Quote from the challenge:

- The existing leaderboard, *ranked* , is in descending order.
- The player's scores, *player* , are in ascending order.

So both sorting and inserts are both redundant. Sorting is redundant because both arrays are already sorted. Inserts are redundant because the score is dense(E.g. tying for second place means both players are second place and third place is **not** skipped) and the player scores are in ascending order.

**Use an index to remember your last placement.**

Basically for every single player score you just want to find count of scores that are higher than the given score.
If removing the redundant operations is not sufficient, you can remember where was the first score higher than you last time and start going from there. Checking every score separately - O(n^2) since you might need to check all the ranks every time. Checking only from the place where you finished in the previous iteration - O(n) since you will go over the ranks array at most once.